# How to sync flutter apps between different UI and size of different phones

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPjD.jpg)

My application is not syncing with different phones. How to solve this problem? Please help in detail explanation?

Comment: I need to know use of MediaQuery for bigger screen adjustments. Please kindly help, I know the use of ListView for smalller ones.

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question as sync is not the appropriate term.

Answer (score 1):

You can build for different screens using

> OrientationBuilder

and

> MediaQuery.

Also, you can use a plugin [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) .

> flutter_screenutil - flutter plugin for adapting screen and font size. Let your UI display a reasonable layout on different screen sizes!
> **Note: This plugin is still under development, and some APIs might not be available yet.**

Comment: I just want to sync it in bigger screens where my layout height becomes smaller than screen height of my AVD. So how can i know what exact size to maintain, to sync it with the screen in easiest way using MediaQuery or Orientation Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Make your container scrollable(`ListView` or other types) so that when screen size change your content will not be hidden

Comment: I want to know for bigger screens to sync my layout.

Comment: I know about ListView and SingleChildScrollView , I just want to know how to set it for bigger screen using MediaQuery or any other options available such that widget fill my entire screen

Answer (score 0):

You want to use MediaQuery class in order to get the height and width of the users screen. You can read about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

To get the user screen height and width you can call this inside your widgets build method:

```
var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Then after you have those variables you can make your other widgets sizes be in proportion to your design. I usually design in AdobeXD and I use the template screen size 640 x 360. Then if I made a specific widget in my design 50x50 in size I set the corresponding widgets height and width in my application by using these formulas:

```
50 / 640.0 * screenHeight;
50 / 360.0 * screenWidth;
```

That way my widget may look different depending on how big the screen of the user is.
You should combine that with what Besufkad Menji said. Use a ListView if you think all of your widgets won't fit on a small screen.

Comment: Sir,I just want to sync it in bigger screens where my layout height becomes smaller than screen height of my AVD. So how can i know what exact size to maintain, to sync it with the screen in easiest way using MediaQuery or Orientation Builder.

Comment: Sir kindly help me for bigger screen adjustment using MediaQuery part, i cant get it how to adjust such that my widgets fill the entire screen.

Comment: You should have posted an example code in your question. But let's say that you have a Scaffold as a top widget. Inside it's build method before returning a Scaffold you should create two variables that I have mentioned in the answer above. Then for each widget you shouldn't just put a fixed height and width but rather you should use the two formulas that I have mentioned in my answer to determine what height and width that widget should have.